# Changing MySQL Temporary File - Permissions Error

Tags: permissions, mysql, selinux

At the moment, MySQL Server is using /tmp as it's temporary directory, and I'd like to change that, because it's running into storage issues.

Following this post: [How to change the MySQL tmp location on CentOS](https://encylia.com/2015/02/06/how-to-change-the-mysql-tmp-location-on-centos/) as I'm on Scientific Linux and generally CentOS works pretty well as an analog, I've done the following, all under `sudo`:

```
mkdir /home/mysqltmp

chmod 1777 /home/mysqltmp

nano /etc/my.cnf

Add below line under the [mysqld] section and save the file
tmpdir=/home/mysqltmp

systemctl restart mysqld
```

This restart fails. If I restore the old my.cnf without the change, it works perfectly, which suggests to me that there's a problem either with the configuration file itself, or with how I've setup permissions, and given my (limited) Linux experience, I'm pretty sure that it's a permissions problem.

UPDATE: Looking at mysqld.log, it appears this is indeed a permissions issue:

```
2018-05-16T00:01:05.211853Z 0 [Note] /usr/sbin/mysqld (mysqld 5.7.22) starting as process 5929 ...
2018-05-16T00:01:05.214159Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: PUNCH HOLE support available
2018-05-16T00:01:05.214186Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Mutexes and rw_locks use GCC atomic builtins
2018-05-16T00:01:05.214191Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Uses event mutexes
2018-05-16T00:01:05.214194Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: GCC builtin __atomic_thread_fence() is used for memory barrier
2018-05-16T00:01:05.214197Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Compressed tables use zlib 1.2.3
2018-05-16T00:01:05.214202Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Using Linux native AIO
2018-05-16T00:01:05.214382Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Number of pools: 1
2018-05-16T00:01:05.214459Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Using CPU crc32 instructions
mysqld: Can't create/write to file '/home/mysqltmp/ibAcknwl' (Errcode: 13 - Permission denied)
2018-05-16T00:01:05.214535Z 0 [ERROR] InnoDB: Unable to create temporary file; errno: 13
2018-05-16T00:01:05.214542Z 0 [ERROR] InnoDB: Plugin initialization aborted with error Generic error
2018-05-16T00:01:05.214548Z 0 [ERROR] Plugin 'InnoDB' init function returned error.
2018-05-16T00:01:05.214551Z 0 [ERROR] Plugin 'InnoDB' registration as a STORAGE ENGINE failed.
2018-05-16T00:01:05.214554Z 0 [ERROR] Failed to initialize builtin plugins.
2018-05-16T00:01:05.214557Z 0 [ERROR] Aborting
```

Does anyone see what I'm doing wrong?

Update 2: This *does* appear to be an selinux thing. `chown` does not fix the problem, and in the audit logs there's a number of AVC denied {write} messages for that directory.

selinux is entirely opque to me - is there a fix for this?

Comment: does `sudo chown mysql.mysql /home/mysqltmp`  help? Though I am more inclined for it to be a SELinux thing....

Comment: See update. It's an SELinux thing.

Answer (score 0):

I came across this very same issue today. It gave me enough hints to have the idea of googling for "*selinux mysql write permission*". Which immediately gave me the answer, which you can read [on this Oracle blog post](https://blogs.oracle.com/jsmyth/selinux-and-mysql). In case Oracle would take down the link as they are quite used to, you can also get [it](https://web.archive.org/web/20190627211932/https://blogs.oracle.com/jsmyth/selinux-and-mysql) from the wayback machine, but be patient and scroll down to get the text.

I will just give here a few hints:

1. Check your selinux status with (root shell) command `getenforce`
2. If it replies with '*ENFORCING*', try setting it to '*PERMISSIVE*' with command `setenforce 0`
3. Then try to restart mysqld and check that it is now working
4. reset selinux back to normal with command `setenforce 1`

Once you have demonstrated that selinux is the culprit for mysqld not working, you can't just disable it, because that is not secure. You have to find out how to add an exception specific to mysqld in its configuration.

For that part I will let you figure out by yourself using the link I gave and SELinux documentation as I am not a specialist and thus would not try to give advice about something I don't fully understand